# How to get all values from the inner maps of a map using a common key?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a map of maps: `HashMap<String, Map<DistinctCode, String>>`.

I need to extract the `String` value from the inner maps just by using a `DistinctCode`. How can I do that in one line or statement?

In other words, I need a method something like this:

```
mapOfMap.find(distinctcode)
```

Is it doable in one line or statement?

Comment: `String string2 = yourMap.get("string1").get(whateverDistinctCodeIs);` This is, assuming `HashMap<String1, Map<distinctcode, String2>> yourMap` and that `String1` and `String2` are `String` class.

Comment: thanks for the response but I do not want to pass string1 I just want to do it by whateverDistinctCodeIs only, since these are distinct for all outer maps, I do not need to pass that in.

Comment: I would edit the title to make it clear that the key you want to use is the distinct code.

Comment: Thanks I'll edit. But could you suggest how Can I do that?

Comment: `Guava's Table` is an alternative to `Map in Map` https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Table

Comment: ^ Thats the right answer

Comment: @Russel not in one line :)  Only way I can think is the obvious to loop over the entry set of the outer map and then get on the inner set.  Also, could your outer map not have multple inner maps that have the distinctCode as a key?

Comment: @AmirAfghani that's not necessary since Java 8. Also, that will return a `Map<String, String>` which is not what OP wants/needs.

Comment: "One line" isn't the same as "one statement".

Comment: All I needed is little bit cleaner code. One line is fine. I just did not want to use puttAll or loop. Thanks Guys!

Comment: @russell Keep in mind that, with what you have explained, there will be a loop. It might be hidden by the Stream API (which is a wonderful tool), but it is not going to be any more efficient because it only takes one line of text to describe what you want the computer to do.

Answer (score 4):

In Java 8

```
List<String> list = map.values().stream().map(m -> m.get(distinctcode)).filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Didn't know `Objects.nonNull`. (+1)

Answer (score 2):

With Java 8 you can do

```
Set<String> strings = mapOfMaps.values().stream()
           .map(m -> m.get(distinctCode))
           .filter(v -> v != null)
           .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DistinctCode dv = ...;

Stream<String> res = 
    mom.values().stream().map(p->p.get(dv)).filter(p->p!=null);
```

Comment: Thanks! I needed something like this.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different Java 8 approach without null filtering:

```
final Set<String> values = mapOfMaps.values().stream()
            .filter(m -> m.containsKey(distinctCode))
            .map(m -> m.get(distinctCode))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet()); //this can be simplified using a static import
```