# Java Streams: get values grouped by inner map key

Tags: java, java-8, grouping, java-stream, collectors

I have `Map<A, Map<B, C>>` and I want to get `Map<B, List<C>>` from it using Java Streams.

I try to do it as follows:

```
public <A, B, C> Map<B, List<C>> groupsByInnerKey(Map<A, Map<B, C>> input) {
    return input.values()
            .stream()
            .flatMap(it -> it.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey));
}
```

What I expect:

- `flatMap` gives a `Stream` of `Map.Entry<B, C>`
- `collect(Collectors.groupingBy(...))` takes function which is applied to `Map.Entry<B, C>` and returns `B`, thus it collects values of `C` into `List<C>`.

But it doesn't compile, literally:

> Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context

at `Map.Entry::getKey` in the last line.

Can someone explain what is wrong or what is the right way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29373026/how-to-get-all-values-from-the-inner-maps-of-a-map-using-a-common-key

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty, not actually, I'm asking about why the expected way of doing this doesn't work. Also, the task is slightly different from the question you referenced.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your Stream is composed of `Map.Entry` objects but want you want to collect is actually the value of the entry, not the entry itself. With your current code, you would be obtaining a `Map<B, List<Map.Entry<B, C>>>`.

As such, you are just missing a call to [`Collectors.mapping`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-). This collector will map the Stream element with the given mapper function and collect that result into the downstream container. In this case, the mapper is `Map.Entry::getValue` (so returning the value from the map entry) and the downstream collector collects into a `List`.

```
public <A, B, C> Map<B, List<C>> groupsByInnerKey(Map<A, Map<B, C>> input) {
    return input.values()
            .stream()
            .flatMap(it -> it.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                 Map.Entry::getKey,
                 Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())
            ));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. So, I was actually confused by the compiler's error message. It should be saying about types mismatch, not about non-static context. :)

Comment: I keep getting `non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context` for `Mep.Entry::getKey`

Comment: Solved it, I had to use `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey`, since I use AbstractMap to create map entries in a stream (does not really make sense since i groupBy but eh)

Answer (score 8):

Your stream pipeline returns a `Map<B, List<Map.Entry<B,C>>>`, not a `Map<B, List<C>>`.

To get what a `Map<B, List<C>>`, you need to add a `mapping` that would map `Map.Entry<B,C>` to `C` :

```
return input.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .flatMap(it -> it.getValue().entrySet().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue,Collectors.toList())));
```