# Collect and map in Java8 Streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

Is there a way to do something like this in Java 8? I have the following interface:

```
public interface MyInterface{
    String groupId();
    Integer value();
}
```

I want to write the following method

```
public static Map<String, List<Integer>> groupByGroupId(Collection<MyInterface> mis){
    //...
}
```

The thing is I cannot just do `map` on the stream as that I lose `MyInterface` information.

```
mis.stream().map(MyInterface::value) // lose groupId
```

Also it's unacceptable to iterate over the collection twice. I mean I could apply groupingBy to get `Map<String, MyInterface>`

```
mis.stream.collect(
    groupingBy(
        MyInterface::groupId
    )
)
```

But with such approach I have to iterate over the resulting map to get what I want. Maybe there is something I could use with

```
groupingBy(classifier, downstreamCollector)
```

But could not find a collector which collects and does mapping while collecting. Is there anything in `JDK` to achieve this without lots pain?

Comment: `Collectors.mapping` as downstream: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34719844/java-streams-get-values-grouped-by-inner-map-key

Comment: @Tunaki thank you, works perfect.